# How to keep html and php result in one line

Tags: php, html, ident

It returns me:

"Situação:
Ativo"

I want:
"Situação: Ativo"

```
<font color="#FFFFFF">Situação<?php
            if($coluna_situacao['usu_situacao'] == "inativo") {
            echo "<div style ='color:#FF5500'>Inativo</div>";
            } 
            else if ($coluna_situacao['usu_situacao'] == "ativo"){ 
                echo "<div style ='color:#00FF04'>Ativo</div>"; 
            }
            else {
                echo "<div style ='color:#FF5500'>Contate a central</div>";
            } ?></font>
```

Comment: Use span instead of div

Comment: Or use `<div style="display: inline; color: #FF5500">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually div is a block element So if you use div it will start with new line, So you need to use any in-line element like span to show your text in-line.

```
<font color="#FFFFFF">Situação<?php
                if($coluna_situacao['usu_situacao'] == "inativo") {
                echo "<em style ='color:#FF5500'>Inativo</em>";
                } 
                else if ($coluna_situacao['usu_situacao'] == "ativo"){ 
                    echo "<em style ='color:#00FF04'>Ativo</em>"; 
                }
                else {
                    echo "<em style ='color:#FF5500'>Contate a central</em>";
                } ?></font>
```

Comment: Please mark answer as right answer...happy coding :)

Comment: @piyush To improve your answer, you may link <em> tag documentation. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_em.asp

Comment: Or just style the element as `inline` or `inline-block` using CSS